# Regex for editing files

Tags: php, regex, replace, find

I have to replace the following in my PHP code:

```
assert('is_array($myArray)');
assert('my_function_call($myVariable)');
```

to make it read like:

```
assert(is_array($myArray));
assert(my_function_call($myVariable));
```

The problem is that it occurs a lot of time in my code files, and I would have to open each and make the change.

I use NetBeans which has a find and replace functionality which uses regex. What regex to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use find replace regex term:

```
assert\(\'is_array\($myArray\)\'\);

assert\(\'my_function_call\($myVariable\)\'\);
```

Escaping the regex characters fixes simple text terms.